# Can mayonnaise actually be a good instrument?

Tags: learning, instruments

Everyone knows what one iconic scene from SpongeBob, where Patrick asks Squidward a question:

> Is mayonnaise an instrument?

To which he responds:

> No, Patrick, mayonnaise is not an instrument.

I've already seen [Context Sensitive](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCT1ZkP03V18LmOj8zbyP-Dw) use mayonnaise as an instrument in his song [Karlson Vibe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OoZky6l400), but when used correctly, is it a good instrument? And if so, is it a good intro to drumming?

Comment: How are we to know that the video linked here employs mayonnaise as an instrument?

Comment: @phoog Mayonnaise is used as a snare in the song, as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-Dv53or4ZU.

Comment: [Maybe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiJUDIFu8dk).

Comment: I suppose the requito version would be mayonaiminorase?

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's disgusting.  Now I would like to know if you want a serious philosophical answer about the meaning of music and "found objects" in modern art and whatnot, or something else.

Comment: Whether a particular instrument is 'good' or not is a matter of opinion and those kind of questions are off topic.

Comment: Have you ever tried getting a tune out of an egg banjo? [imnsho, this question is the merest hint above trolling & ought to be closed by now.]

Comment: There are better sauces of musical sounds than mayonnaise, surely? Tomtomato ketchup comes to mind... As well as bassic white sauce.

Comment: Welcome! Take a second to look over [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and how to avoid [opinion-based answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). The problem with this question as-is is not the fact that it takes a silly idea seriously (yes, Squidward has an overly reductive and narrow-minded definition of "instrument"), but the word "good." If you'd like, you might be able to edit this into an on-topic question, by asking the sort of things that get fact-based answers, like "how should I splat the mayo to get the sound I want?"

Comment: I wonder if some kind of xylophone-like mayonnaise dipping instrument can be constructed from little cans with mayonnaise in it. You only need amplification, or a good hearing.. the resulting plop-plop sounds won't carry far, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be pedantic, the instrument on the video is a sampler in a DAW, and the "mayonnaise" part is a heavily processed sample of slapping a blob of mayonnaise on table.

Usually "drumming" is understood as the art of percussion by hitting objects with sticks or other implements, and since these are not involved I would not consider this a good introduction. Points for creative trolling and surviving for a hour without closing the question, though.

Comment: I was not even trolling, I was actually curious. I'm so weird.